# Query (with Cosmos DB) on Partition key results in multiple Partition key ranges, How is this possible?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, partition

I have a DB in Cosmos DB and a container defined within it. Throughput is associated with the DB (2000 RU/sec) and shared by container. The idea is to define few containers all of which will share the throughput defined at DB level.
I have inserted around 128000000 collections in the container (around 180 GB of data size and 38 GB of index size).

When I query the collection based on partition key like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM c 
WHERE c.partition_key_value = 'bbababab-asas-asas-23we-79ffrreesff'
```

The results of per-partition query stats show that it queried 2 partitions which is confusing..

Isn't should be querying only single partition as all the data should be residing in one partition?

For some other cases, it queries as many as 4 partition key ranges.

Can someone explain this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56943309/differentiate-between-partition-keys-partition-key-ranges-in-azure-cosmos-db. This explains the relation between a PartitionKey and PartitionKey range.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I have gone through that link, but what is not clear is though system shall have 5 PK ranges, but when queried for a specific PK, why would it search in all PK ranges (and recieved data as well from multiple of them) when the data should be present in only 1 PK range (i.e. in 1 physical partition)